# Event for one view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an event which is thrown when a button on the keyboard is pressed. I want this event to be called for only one view. For now, in my Layout view I have:

```
<body onkeydown="theMethod()">
```

But this is getting called in all the pages of the application. How to call the only for one view? The views don't have body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the event dynamically in the one view that you want it to be fired.

In the view that you *do* want key events on the body to be handled, add code like this to the view's markup:

```
$(function(){
    $("BODY").keydown(theMethod);
});
```

This is a jQuery example (you can do without jQuery but it's included with MVC scaffolding and is elegant for situations like this).

Abstracting event handling from inline declarations is a good practice and makes scenarios like this easier to handle.